# Disconnected USB device still visible in Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, usb, device-manager, libusb

I have a USB device that, when a certain hard problem is encountered and after I unplug it, refuses to disappear from `Device Manager`. Even there's no driver for it in memory (`Process Explorer`, System), even if I refresh the view, even if uninstalled. After re-install, it shows the yellow warning, telling me that it cannot be started, error 10. The only solution I found is the obvious reboot, is there another one ? (I even had a blue screen with one of the restarts)

**EDIT** It is not a Device Manager refresh problem: the port with the "connected" device cannot be used anymore. When I plug something else nothing happens (even in `USBDeview`).

**EDIT 2**

```
>sc stop <Name>
invalid command for this type of service

>DeviceCheck disable "USB\VID_0666&PID_666A&REV_0000"
USB\VID_0666&PID_666A\<Some name>                           : Disable failed
No devices disabled.

>DeviceCheck status USB "USB\VID_0666&PID_666A&REV_0000"
USB\VID_0666&PID_666A\<Some name>
    Name: <Nice name>
    Driver is running.
1 matching device(s) found.
```

After enable & disable from "Device Manager", the driver (sys) is unloaded from memory (but it stays in the list with an warning icon) and:

```
>DeviceCheck status USB "USB\VID_0666&PID_666A&REV_0000"
USB\VID_0666&PID_666A\<Some name>
    Name: <Nice name>
    Device has a problem: 10.
1 matching device(s) found.
```

Related question: how does "Device manager" succeeds in unloading it?

Comment: Maybe if I move it to http://stackoverflow.com/ it will receive more attention ?

Comment: In the `"Command"`sequences I replaced VID, PID & names for not involving the company.

Comment: The driver is obviously misbehaving. If you say `libusb`, you might want to look into [WinUSB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel I agree about the driver, I'll try to see libusb 1.0 when I'll have the time (changing the version is not possible for the moment). But what worries me more is the system's answer to the situation: no sys loaded, no USB device plugged, but the driver shown as available (with an warning, true) by Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

when you insert your usb device the windows automatically install its driver so you could see it Device Manager.

so just for saving time and not to install the usb driver every time you insert it.the windows keep it

Comment: It's not about having an installed driver, but about keeping the device visible in `Device Manager` after disconnection.